# Problems in Local Terminal in Android's Developer Menu

Tags: terminal, bugs, 9.0-pie, oneplus-3, developer-options

I am currently having a problem in my Android 9's local terminal from the developer menu, where keys such as `$` are turned into their counterpart in the QWERTY keyboard without pressing shift (for example a `$` is turned into `4`). The actual numbers are not affected, just the other characters (I was trying to print an environment variable, and the `$` sign turned into `4`). Anyone have experienced this problem before?

Comment: You can use any terminal app. Termux is a good one.

Comment: I know Termux app, but I want to try the local one. It used to run fine on previous Android versions, but this one somehow not detecting the special characters.